# where is the data in the bundle of onsaveinstance() method stored on the device?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

1) Where is the data in the bundle of onsaveinstance() method stored on the device? Is it stored in the data/data directory or on sqlite DB or elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will be in memory. As soon as your application closes, it will be cleared out.

Comment: then how will the onCreate() method get the saved bundle with stored information from previous session, when the user starts the application after its cleared out of memory? I think the android persists the information in bundle somewhere. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Did you validate that? onCreate() of which activity? start activity?

Comment: The android documentation says that the signature of oncreate method is "protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)". Is it not the same bundle that is saved using onSavedInstance()? I am refering to the onCreate() method of the activity that calls the savedInstanceState().